# Html - How to position textbox/inputs in the same div?

Tags: html, css

imagine I have this div

```
<div class="div_pin" id="divOne">
<input name="pin1" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
<input name="pin2" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
<input name="pin3" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
<input name="pin4" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
</div>
```

The inputs are all together, how do I postion them?

Comment: Where you want to pos them?

Comment: Like four spaces between them, but I can't add spaces

Comment: The short answer is you use `CSS`

Comment: If you means changing the layout, an easy way is using <table>

Comment: Don't use tables unless it's tabular data, forms are not. Use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want vertical spacing.

Add class to your inputs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div_pin" id="divOne">
  <input class="MyInput" name="pin1" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
  <input class="MyInput" name="pin2" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
  <input class="MyInput" name="pin3" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
  <input class="MyInput" name="pin4" type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" />
</div>
```

Style your inputs.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .MyInput{
        margin:10px 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: No need to set a class, you can do by the input name. This can do individual styling, if you want all together just use the type=text

Comment: targeting the name attribute could adversely affect other elements within the site that we are unaware of.

Comment: In that case use the wrapper div, still is not need to add one more class

Answer (score 0):

You can style like this:

**Individual (by name)**

```
input[name=pin1]{
    display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 20px;

}
```

**ALL (by Type)**

```
input[type=text]{
    display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 20px;
 }
```

If you want to use just in this markup HTML and not the all website just use the wrapper div before the input rule:

```
.div_pin input[type=text]{
        display: inline-block;
         margin-right: 20px;
     }
```

Comment: And you can add that into a <style> element in your html page, or a file like styles.css which is imported into your html page.

Comment: I have added 1 because i liked ur answer.  Thank u. Now it is 0.